# Django passing 2 parameter from HTML template to views function

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I want to pass 2 parameters to my view function, in order to delete specific record from table.

There is M2M connection on which I want to work so I have to pass 2 parameters for 2 different objects.

Model:

```
class Products(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=2, blank=True)

class Meals(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
     ingredient = models.ManyToManyField(Products, related_name="products")
```

views:

```
def remove_ingredient(request, pk, name):
     meal = Meals.objects.get(pk=pk)
     prod = Products.objects.get(name=name)
     meal.ingredient.remove(prod)
     return HttpResponse(status=204)
```

url patterns:

```
urlpatterns = [ 
    path("meal_detail/<int:pk>/",MealDetailView.as_view(), name="meal_detail" ),
    path("meal_detail/<int:pk>/", remove_ingredient, name="remove_ingredient")
]
```

HTML template:

```
 <a class="hyperlink-off" href="{% url 'remove_ingredient' pk=object.pk  name=ingredient.name %}">
       Remove
 </a>
```

As you can see I want to pass 2 arguments from HTML template to my function (primary key of `Meal` and name of product which I want to remove from `Meals.ingredient`).

But in the same time URL pattern is receiving 2 arguments and its trying to generate link to website based on both of them when it needs just one. I tried even to force function to stay at the same page by passing `HttpResponse(status=204)`.

How can I exclude one of arguments passed from HTML to `urls.py` or is there any other way to pass variables to views function from html template?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`re_path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urls/#re-path) in your `remove_ingredient` URL, and also consider being descriptive with the URL so that the action is visible to the user.

```
urlpatterns = [ 
    path("meal_detail/<int:pk>/", MealDetailView.as_view(), name="meal_detail" ),
    re_path("^meal_detail/<int:pk>/remove/(?P<name>\w+)/$", remove_ingredient, name="remove_ingredient")
]
```

Another thing to consider is that an action which changes the state of your application, e.g. changes data in the database like this, should really be done as a `POST` request because that enables you to utilise django's security features like CSRF protection.

You wouldn't want something which changes data in your system to be exposed & vulnerable to attack if someone discovers a URL which can be requested from outside of your web application in order to change your data.

There is some further reading on this here; https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/188860/why-shouldnt-a-get-request-change-data-on-the-server